# Pandas masking the column replaces non matched value to NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe

```
d = {
    "cid": [1, 3, 3],
    "txt": ["Kakashi is GOAT", "Eleven is El", "Hello agian"],
     "anime": ['Kakashi ', 'el', 'mouse']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['code'] = df['anime'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

I need to create a new column `code` which will contain value from code if anime is present in txt else 999

This is my mask

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.anime.lower() in x.txt.lower(), axis=1)
df['newCol'] = 999
df['newCol'] = df.loc[mask, 'code']
```

but this gives me float values and the replaces the `999` as NaN

Output :

```
df
   cid              txt     anime  code  newCol
0    1  Kakashi is GOAT  Kakashi      0     0.0
1    3     Eleven is El        el     1     1.0
2    3      Hello agian     mouse     2     NaN
```

Expected :

```
df
   cid              txt     anime    code  newCol
0    1  Kakashi is GOAT    Kakashi      0     0
1    3     Eleven is El      el         1     1
2    3      Nothing         mouse       2     999
```

Note that I need to do it the masking way there are various methods in which this can be achieved though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip the `mask` step and just assign the `newCol` values using (almost) the same lambda function:

```py
df['newCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.code if x.anime.lower() in x.txt.lower() else 999, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   cid              txt     anime  code  newCol
0    1  Kakashi is GOAT  Kakashi      0       0
1    3     Eleven is El        el     1       1
2    3      Hello agian     mouse     2     999
```

Note that `el` matches against `Eleven` and `El` in the string `Eleven is El`. If you want to avoid that, you should use a regex match instead, using word boundaries to ensure `el` can *only* match `El`, not `Eleven`:

```
import re

df['newCol'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.code if re.search(rf'\b{x.anime}\b', x.txt, re.I) else 999, axis=1)
```

The output is the same. Note that by using the `re.I` (case-insensitive) flag, we can avoid the need to convert both strings to lower-case.

Comment: I get it, but how can I make my masking solution work??

Comment: @YashwinKumarPoddar `df.loc[mask, 'newCol'] = df['code']`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your statement about doing it masking way, below can give you the required result using numpy(np):

```
df['newCol'] = np.where(mask, df["code"], 999 )
```